# Change price using select option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

I am using Cart66 which does not change the price of the cart until after the user views their cart. I need a way to change the price on the current item so the user knows the price has changed. I figured this could be done using jquery/js but cannot figure out how.

Increase/Decrease the price of "cart66-price-value" based off the value within "()" of "cart66-select" option text.

```
<script class="cart66-select">
<option value="A">Coral</option>
<option value="B">Passion Fruit (+5.00)</option>
</script>
<strong class="cart66-price-value">$24.00</strong>
```

Comment: What did you try? I'd say it would be much easier to put the value in the value field.

Comment: The value is unique value that Cart66 is using to track the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="cart66-select">
    <option value="A" price="10">Coral</option>
    <option value="B" price="5">Passion Fruit (+5.00)</option>
</select>
<strong class="cart66-price-value">$<span id="price">24.00</span></strong>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".cart66-select").change(function(){
            var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(':selected').attr('price')).toFixed(2);
            jQuery("#price").html(price);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `price.toFixed(2)` to get the price with two decimals

Comment: This works great, and is similar to what I had. However, Cart66 does not allow the ability to add custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using jQuery yes [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2882744/aaron-bacon). Look at an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra4dY/1/) that did

```
<select class="cart66-select">
    <option value="$24.00">Coral</option>
    <option value="$29.00">Passion Fruit (+5.00)</option>
</select>
<strong class="cart66-price-value">$24.00</strong>

var changePrice = function()
{
    var select = $(".cart66-select"),
        displayPrice = $(".cart66-price-value");

    select.change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        displayPrice.text(selected);
    });
}

changePrice();
```

Comment: This works perfectly! However, because I am using Cart66, the value attribute is already being used to track the item with a unique identifier. What I need is a way to use "(+5.00)" to increase the price.

Comment: Now I understand what was the real problem. In this case, the regular expression solves! Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Ra4dY/2/